# Why is my batch script not working...?

Tags: batch-file

I'm new here.

I'm trying to make a simple batch script that can change a password. When I execute it, the passwords never match, and the script is restarted. (I'm on windows 7)

```
@echo off
:Start
cls
set /p newpass=What would you like your new password to be? 
set /p passconfirm=Please retype your new password. 
if %passconfirm% == %newpass% goto True
cls
echo Your passwords do not match, restarting script.
pause
goto Start

:True 
echo %username%
set /p user=Is this the account you wish to change the password? 
if 
%user% == Yes 
goto True1 
cls
set /p user= Please enter the username that you wish to change the password for. 
goto True1


:True1 
cls
net user %user% %newpass%
echo Your password has been changed. 
pause 
Exit
```

Comment: Your if statement is missing an `if`.

Comment: I tried that, it said something about a syntax missing, the error message was so quick I couldn't see it. The only way  I could get past the first command was by taking the if's out.

Comment: run the batch file in cmd, not by double clicking it, in order to see the error messages

Comment: Open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking the script.

Comment: How would I open the script from cmd, it's a long script and it won't copy and paste.

Comment: Just by typing the name of the file that contains the script e.g. batchfilename.bat

Comment: The spaces around the `=` sign are the problem `if %user%<space>==<space>Yes`

Comment: Good news, the error message is "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: @Noodles, the spaces around `==` are no problem; you seem to confuse that with the syntax for `set` where spaces around `=` do cause troubles...

Comment: Voting to close because of lack of attempting to debug; down-voting because of absolutely uselass question title...

Comment: @aschipfl It's your choice, and I'm okay with that.

Comment: Actually my comment and the votes were intended to incite you to improve your post accordingly -- without success apparently...

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you so much, but someone already fixed it... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the batch code improved for working most likely as expected:

```
@echo off
rem Setup a local environment for this batch script.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:EnterPassword
cls
rem Clear entered password from previous run kept when
rem user of batch file just hits key RETURN or ENTER.
set "NewPassword="
set "ConfirmPassword="

rem Prompt the user twice for the password.
set /P "NewPassword=What would you like as new password? "
set /P "ConfirmPassword=Please retype your new password:     "

rem First check if user entered anything at all.
if "!NewPassword!" == "" goto EnterPassword
rem Next check if user entered the same string twice.
if "!ConfirmPassword!" == "!NewPassword!" goto PasswordConfirmed
echo.
echo Your passwords do not match, restarting script.
echo.
pause
goto EnterPassword

:PasswordConfirmed
echo.
echo Current user accout name is: %username%
echo.

rem Define Y as default answer for next prompt and define
rem the current user name as user to change the password for.
set "UserPrompt=Y"
set "User=%USERNAME%"

set /P "UserPrompt=Is this the account you wish to change the password (Y/n)? "

rem Compare case-insenstive the answer with Y and with YES.
if /I "!UserPrompt!" == "y"   goto SetPassword
if /I "!UserPrompt!" == "yes" goto SetPassword

echo.
echo Please enter the user name that you wish to change the password for.
echo.
set /P "User=User name: "

:SetPassword
cls
rem %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "!user!" "!NewPassword!"
if not errorlevel 1 echo Your password has been changed.
echo.
endlocal
pause
exit /B
```

`Start` is an internal command. Therefore it is advisable not using this string as name of a label although this is possible.

`Exit` without parameter `/B` always exits the current command process which makes debugging a batch file difficult.

For debugging this batch file remove the first line before saving the batch file, then open a command prompt window and run the batch file from within this window by typing its name with complete path enclosed in double quotes. For example if this batch file is stored on your desktop with the name `Change Password.bat`, you need to run in command prompt window

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Change Password.bat"
```

Once the batch file is working fine, insert `@echo off` again at top and remove `/B` from command `exit` which makes sense here for safety reasons.

Double clicking on a batch file results in executing `cmd.exe` with option `/C` which means close after batch processing terminated and so the error message output by Windows command processor on a syntax error can't be read. Opening a command prompt window results in executing `cmd.exe` with option `/K` which means keep command process running after batch processing terminated making it possible to see error messages. Run in command prompt window `cmd /?` for help on available options of Windows command processor.

When user of batch file hits just <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on prompting for a string the environment variable is still not defined if not defined before, or keeps its value if already defined. This behavior is used here to check if the user enters a new password at all and define default values for the other user prompts.

This block in code in question results in a syntax error on execution:

```
if
%user% == Yes
goto True1
```

A syntax error results always in an immediate exit of batch processing as it can be seen on running the batch file without `@echo off` from within a command prompt window.

On checking answer on a YES/NO user prompt the comparison should be always done case-insensitive which means using parameter `/I` on string comparison.

The strings entered by the user and assigned to the local environment variables are referenced using delayed expansion to prevent an exit of batch processing or an unwanted batch processing when the user enters a string containing special characters like a double quote or angle brackets.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF "%passconfirm%"=="%newpass%" goto True
```

The syntax is specific, `if parm op parm dothis` - all on one line (so this problem is repeated later in the script). The quotes provide some protection against spaces in the input.

Ordinarily, you'd run a batch file from the command prompt. Just place the commands into a file name *something*.bat and run from the prompt using just *something*. Note that your `Exit` command will terminate the `cmd` instance. If you remove it, you will be returned to the prompt.

`cls` clears the screen. If you place a `pause` before the `cls` then you will be able to see the results of the instruction.

Comment: I tried both of your commands, the first one didn't do much but the second one (if parm op....) gave me a "op was unexpected at this time"

Comment: `if parm op parm dothis` is a generic template. `parm` is a parameter, `op` is an operator. operators may be `==` `equ` `lss` `neq` `gtr` `geq` or `leq` - `op` is none of these, hence the report. "didn't do much" is impossible to decode.

Comment: By "didn't do much" I meant it didn't change the way the script executed.